# Error 'reg' is not recognizable while installing Android Studio and SDK

Tags: android, android-studio, installation

Here is what happened while i tried to install Android Studio on my Windows 8.1 PC!
I tried uninstalling and reinstalling a couple of times with the same result.

[image: Error while installing Android Studio]

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Uncheck the checkbox for Intel HAXM during installation of Android Studio

[image]

When Android Studio installation is complete, go to your SDK manager and download Intel HAXM from there

[image]

You can then follow the [instructions](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows) to install Intel HAXM from that point.

Answer (score 0):

Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM) is a hardware-assisted virtualization engine that uses Intel Virtualization Technology to speed up Android development.
So i think you have got a problem in HAX>>>
First of all,

> Click on Turn Window Features on and off in your control panel.
>   Uncheck Hyper-V option and restart your system.

That also if does not work then>>>
Follow the following steps:

> > 1.Press F10 (Computer Set Up) - BIOS - Security -System Security -Enter - Virtual Technology (VTX)-Enable-File
> >     then,Save and Exit
> >     2.Goto sdk Folder:
> >     F:\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager Run
> >     intelhaxm-android.exe
> >     3.You should be seeing a dialog box which quotes,
> >     "Completed Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager Set Up Wizard.
>
> Click the Finish Button to exit the wizard"

After all this,try running the emulator in android studio where you will see HAX is working & your problem is solved...